# How to route/link to a PDF file in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, routes

I'm trying to retrieve a client side pdf file to display in the browser. Tried your normal href, path relative to the html file, and it doesn't work.

```
<a href="../assets/file.pdf>Get File</a>
```

And using routing doesn't work either, or I'm not using the right tag...

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path:"resume", redirectTo: '../assets/file.pdf' },
  { path: '', component: AppComponent }
])
```

Not sure if Routing is the way to go either, I have only learned to route components based on their documentation.

Comment: Could you please give little more info

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`<a href="..` should work. I think the problem is the path for your pdf file. Did you try `<a href="/assets/file.pdf>`, instead of `../assets`?

Comment: You're right. I was thinking of the path relative to the html file, rather than the root of the folder.

Comment: Edmar I'm in the same scenario but the files that should be donwloaded are multiple and I can't create each single map in app routing because the files are uploaded from external app... How can I manage my shenario ?

Answer (score -4):

I have an another solution. I use this in my project:

```
{ path: 'assets/file.pdf', redirectTo: '../assets/file.pdf'}
```

and I use routerLink to get the file like this:

```
<button class="btn-style" routerLink="/assets/file.pdf" routerLinkActive="active">Get File</button>
```

I hope it will be help someone :) it works with Angular 6 too.

Comment: Yes , but why ?

Comment: this option is ok when you have the pdf file in the root folder. but I think the best was is you create an endpoint then click on the button, call that endpoint then send the file  as a response